# Realtime Synchronization of two GIT bare repositaries

Tags: git

Please forgive me, if my requirement is already asked earlier.
I have two bare repositaries (r1 and r2) in two offices.
Users will be keep on pushing to these two bare repositaries.

Question is:

I want these two bare repositaries sync automatically using hooks (with all branches and commits).

ie.

If a push is made to r1 all the updates need to be sync'd to r2 and

If a push is made to r2 all the updates need to be sync'd to r1

Please share post-update hooks for both these repos!

Im new to GIT. Please help me the best and simple solution.
Please note that there is no primary/secondary bare repo here.
Also, this requirement is not for the purpose of backup.
These two bare repositaries need to be updated one always.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Srini

Comment: If you want them to be always in sync, why not just use a single one? Moreover, if you have the networking infrastructure for them to sync securely, it should not be too hard to make one visible on both offices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem here is that we do not have such network infrastructure. However, the sync between the bare repos would take place over a different network/internet line. I believe my requirement is for a multisite setup.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to believe that you can set up a connection between the bare repositories in two offices to sync but not for one office to push to the repo in the other office....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [post-receive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#post-receive) hook to send your changes to the other repository, but sooner or later you would run in the situation where both repositories get different changes at the same time and your sync will start to fail.

If you have some way to sync both repositories in real time, think about using exactly that way to provide access to a single repository.

Comment: Yes. Push failed while trying to push from r1 to r2 while r2 having different work. Thanks for your time.